# How to calculate effect tests in linear regression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am using statsmodels to run a linear regression of a pandas dataset, including both a categorical (Handedness; 3 levels) and a continuous (Age) variable as predictors. I am looking for a simple way to test the effects of Handedness, Age and their interaction - that is, beyond the effect of a specific dummy variable.
I do the following:

```
res = smf.ols(formula="Score ~ C(Handedness, Sum) * center(Age)", data=myData).fit()
print(res3.params)
```

and get the following parameters:

```
Intercept                                         198.188525
C(Handedness, Sum)[S.Ambidextrous]                -12.824061
C(Handedness, Sum)[S.Left]                         11.243362
center(Age)                                         2.659525
C(Handedness, Sum)[S.Ambidextrous]:center(Age)      4.216525
C(Handedness, Sum)[S.Left]:center(Age)             -1.568143
```

I would like to perform f-tests for all the effects in my model: Handedness, Age and their interaction. 
I was able to perform each of them separately using the f_test method:

```
HandednessEffect = np.array(([ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
AgeEffect = np.array(([ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ]))
HandednessXAgeEffect = np.array(([ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
print("Effect Tests:")
print("Handedness\t\t", (res.f_test(HandednessEffect )))
print("Age\t\t", (res.f_test(AgeEffect)))
print("Handedness* Age\t", (res.f_test(HandednessXAgeEffect )))
```

and get:

```
Effect Tests:
Handedness       <F test: F=array([[ 1.14330425]]), p=0.3248142242736258, df_denom=68, df_num=2>
Age              <F test: F=array([[ 0.14232477]]), p=0.7071555851484095, df_denom=68, df_num=1>
Handedness * Age     <F test: F=array([[ 0.03297983]]), p=0.9675735457292447, df_denom=68, df_num=2>
```

I also tried using the wald_test_terms() method to combine the terms, but if I understand correctly, it combines the terms based on names, so if I do:

```
print(res.wald_test_terms(skip_single=True, combine_terms=['Handedness','Age',':center(Age)']))
```

The first term, for example, combines all the terms with the word Handedness in them: that is, the two categorical terms (which is what I want), but also the interaction term (which I want as a separate term).

Is there any automatic way to calculate all the effect tests for a model without specifying each one separately? In JMP software for example, this is part of the default output of a regression analysis. Any ideas?

Comment: try anova_lm http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.anova.anova_lm.html http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/interactions_anova.html starting at `in 40` type 3 tests the main effect separate from the interaction effect

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing, what will be the equivalent of this if I fit a mixed model instead? For example: vc = {'SubjectID': '0 + C(SubjectID)'}
res2 = smf.mixedlm("Score ~ C(Visit, Sum) * C(Group, Sum)", data, groups=data['Group'], vc_formula=vc)

Comment: anova_lm is only available for OLS, but `wald_test_terms(skip_single=False)` should also work to separately test report main and interaction effects, AFAICS.